# how can I access $formatters.push function validity in parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have a directive called players which I use to decide how many players are at which position on a team. I have 4 of these, one for goal keeper, defence, mid-field and forward, so it might look something like this (the + and - are increment and decrement buttons):

```
- Forwards: 2 +
- Mid-Field: 4 +
- Defence: 4 +
- Goal Keeper: 1 +
```

I validate the increment to make sure it doesn't go over 11, but how can I access the maxPlayers validity in another class?

```
require: any = '^ngModel';
    restrict: string = 'A';

    link: ng.IDirectiveLinkFn = (scope: any,
        element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery,
        attributes: any,
        ngModel: ng.INgModelController) => {

        scope.getTotalPlayers = (): number => {
            return this.playerStateService.getTotalPlayers();
        };

        function customValidation(modelValue: number) {
            var totalPlayers: number = scope.getTotalPlayers();

            if (totalPlayers > 11) {
                ngModel.$render = () => {
                    ngModel.$setValidity('maxPlayers', false);
                };
            } else {
                ngModel.$setValidity('maxPlayers', true);
            }
            return modelValue;
        }
        ngModel.$parsers.push(customValidation);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to achieve? More specifically, why you function the number of players checking in outside of the directive?

I see two ways.

- Getting to the controller function. In **controller** write something like `$scope.myForm.myModelController.$parsers[0]`.
- Create the controller or service the number of players check function. Then transfer this function to the directive. That is, to make the logic verification of the directive.

Examples:

**First way**.

```
function ExampleController($scope){
   var validityFunc = $scope.myForm.myModelController.$parsers[0];
}
```

**Second way**.

In controller:

```
function ExampleController($scope){
   $scope.validityFunc = function(){ return totalPlayers>11;};
}
```

In directive:

```
function customValidation(modelValue: number) {
        ngModel.$setValidity('maxPlayers', !scope.validityFunc());.
        return modelValue;
    }
ngModel.$parsers.push(customValidation);
```